# Identifying specific button in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

so I want to get a specific value if a button is clicked in my form, but somehow its listening on all buttons and not only the buttons in my form.

Instead of the javascript example below I also tried calling the class by

```
$('.modifygap').bind('click', function (e) {
```

but in this example the value didnt get set correctly.

Here is my html:

```
<button type="button" id="anotherbutton">Another</button>

<form action="editortoken_information" id="showtoken" method="POST">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="modifygap" id="modifygap" class="modifygap"
    value="14" data-value="test">14</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="modifygap" id="modifygap" class="modifygap" 
    value="15" data-value="test">15</button>

</form>
```

And here is my javascript function:

```
$(document.getElementById("showtoken")).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         document.getElementById('tokenindex').value = this.getAttribute("data-value");
    })
})
```

I thought by listening only on the specific id it would only detect button clicks in the form. But for some reason it is listening to all button clicks.

Comment: Two elements can't have same id ,`id="modifygap"` is twice

Comment: ID is meant to be unique

Comment: You should only have one `class` attribute

Comment: is there a problem if i have buttons with the same id and dont really call them by id or can i just not define an id for each button?

Comment: You should have unique `id`

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.value` to get the value of clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.modifygap').bind('click', function (e) {
    console.log('e', e.target.getAttribute("data-value"))
  });  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="anotherbutton">Another</button>



    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary modifygap" type="submit" name="modifygap" id="modifygap"
    value="14" data-value="test14">14</button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary modifygap" type="submit" name="modifygap" id="modifygap" 
    value="15" data-value="test15">15</button>
```